# Bundle exec rake db:migrate does not work (and neither does rake db:migrate), Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, rake, bundler

I am running a Rails 3 app on Ubuntu (EC2), I have rake locked at version 0.8.7 and when I do rake db:migrate I get the usual:

```
  You have already activated rake 0.9.2.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.8.7. Using bundle exec may solve this.
```

However when I do bundle exec rake db:migrate, I get the same response..

??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things that you can try:

1. Upgrade Ruby to 1.9.3 which will provide Rake 0.9.2.2
2. Add this to your Gemfile `gem 'rake' , '>= 0.9.2'` and run `bundle update` again.
3. Worst case, delete your Gemfile.lock and regenerate it again using `bundle install`

Comment: These might allow Stpn to proceed, but the real question is why 0.9.2.2 is being activated given that it was run as `bundle exec rake ...`

Comment: I am trying the Gemfile.lock delete approach now, since I actually need Rake 0.8.7 (some other gem depends on it).